# What is the proper way to determine the end of a mouse drag using Rx?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0, system.reactive

I am slowly learning how to use [Reactive Extensions for .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/ee794896.aspx) with WPF. There a few beginner examples about how simple it is to write drag-drop or drawing routines but they are all extremely simple. I'm trying to go one step further and it's not obvious to me what the "proper" way is.

The examples all show how you can define streams of events from `MouseDown`, `MouseMove`, and `MouseUp`

```
var mouseDown = from evt in Observable.FromEvent<MouseButtonEventArgs>(..., "MouseDown")
                select evt.EventArgs.GetPosition(...);

var mouseMoves = from evt in Observable.FromEvent<MouseEventArgs>(..., "MouseMove")
                 select evt.EventArgs.GetPosition(...);

var mouseUp = Observable.FromEvent<MouseButtonEventArgs>(..., "MouseUp");
```

And then how you can easily do things during a `MouseDrag` (this displays the co-ordinates of the rectangle created from the starting drag point to the current mouse position)

```
var mouseDrag = from start in mouseDown
                from currentPosition in mouseMoves.TakeUntil(mouseUp)
                select new Rect(Math.Min(start.X, currentPosition.X),
                                Math.Min(start.Y, currentPosition.Y),
                                Math.Abs(start.X - currentPosition.X),
                                Math.Abs(start.Y - currentPosition.Y));

mouseDrag.Subscribe(x =>
             {
                 Info.Text = x.ToString();
             });
```

My question is, what is the "proper" way to accomplish a task at the end of the mouse drag? Originally, I thought I could do something like this:

```
mouseDrag.Subscribe(
     onNext: x =>
             {
                 Info.Text = x.ToString();
             },
     onCompleted: () =>
              {
                 // Do stuff here...except it never gets called
              });
```

Reading more of the documentation, though, it seems that `onCompleted` is called when there is no more data (ever) and when the object can be disposed.

So the first option that seems plausable is subscribing to the `mouseUp` event and doing something there.

```
mouseUp.Subscribe(x =>
           {
              // Do stuff here..
           }
```

But then at this point, I may as well go back to just use the "normal" `MouseLeftButtonUp` event handler.

Is there another way to determine when the `mouseDrag` is "completed" (or when the `TakeUntil(mouseUp)`) occurs and perform some action then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sequence never completes because the source (MouseDown) never completes (it is an event). It's worth pointing out that a `IObservable` cannot call `OnComplete` of a subscriber more than once, it's part of the contract (`OnNext* (OnCompleted|OnError)?`).

To find out when the`mouseMove.TakeUntil(mouseUp)` sequence completes, you'll need to hook into the call to `SelectMany`:

```
public static IDisposable TrackDrag(this UIElement element, 
    Action<Rect> dragging, Action dragComplete)
{
    var mouseDown = Observable.FromEvent(...);
    var mouseMove = Observable.FromEvent(...);
    var mouseUp = Observable.FromEvent(...);

    return (from start in mouseDown
            from currentPosition in mouseMove.TakeUntil(mouseUp)
                    .Do(_ => {}, () => dragComplete())
            select new Rect(Math.Min(start.X, currentPosition.X),
                            Math.Min(start.Y, currentPosition.Y),
                            Math.Abs(start.X - currentPosition.X),
                            Math.Abs(start.Y - currentPosition.Y));
            ).Subscribe(dragging);
}
```

Then you can use it like so:

```
element.TrackDrag(
    rect => { },
    () => {}
);
```

For the interest of clarity, here is the LINQ expression using the underlying extension methods:

```
return mouseDown.SelectMany(start =>
{
    return mouseMove
        .TakeUntil(mouseUp)
        .Do(_ => {}, () => dragComplete())
        .Select(currentPosition => new Rect(...));
})
.Subscribe(dragging);
```

That is, for each value from mouseDown a new sequence will be subscribed to. When *that* sequence completes, call dragComplete().

Comment: Yes -- I realized after my first try didn't work that the OnCompleted way is not the way to go. Thanks for the more complete explanation and including Do() :)