# Detect MouseDown and MouseMove events with Reactive Extensions

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, system.reactive

I have the following code to listen to kick off a drag drop event from a WPF ListView.
The idea is that a mouse down event will be followed by a mouse move.  Once the mouse has moved more than the minimum distance, the drag drop action will begin.

```
var mouseDowns = Observable.FromEventPattern<MouseEventArgs>(this, "PreviewMouseDown");
        var mouseMoves = Observable.FromEventPattern<MouseEventArgs>(this, "MouseMove").
            Where(
                x =>
                    x.EventArgs.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed ||
                    x.EventArgs.RightButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed);

        var drag = from mouseDown in mouseDowns
                   from mouseMove in mouseMoves
                   let initialPosition = mouseDown.EventArgs.GetPosition(null)
                   let currentPosition = mouseMove.EventArgs.GetPosition(null)
                   let mouseDifference = initialPosition - currentPosition
                   //where
                   //    (Math.Abs(mouseDifference.X) > MinimumDragDistance ||
                   //    Math.Abs(mouseDifference.Y) > MinimumDragDistance)
                   select mouseDifference;


        dragSubscription = drag.Subscribe(_ =>
         {
             Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("x: {0} y: {1}", _.X, _.Y));
             var dataObject = GetDataObject();
             DragDrop.DoDragDrop(this, dataObject, DragDropEffects.Move);
         });
```

The problem is that in the Linq, whenever a PreviewMouseDown event fires that meets the criteria, only one mouseMove event is caught, meaning that when I include the `where` statement in the list, the mouseDifference is always 0, which doesn't meet the condition.

Is there a way to allow multiple mouseMove events to happen, until one that matches the criteria occurs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to answer the question with the code sample in the following question:

[Using Rx over events on a WPF UserControl, why does the control receive a mousedown and mousemove when the window is maximized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9263510/using-rx-over-events-on-a-wpf-usercontrol-why-does-the-control-receive-a-moused?rq=1)